# Angular 9 unable to run storybooks on ivy enabled library if library imports another ivy enabled library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, storybook

In Angular 8 without Ivy enabled I was able to code with a mono repo watching the library I was working on and running an app which that imported the library whilst running Storybook as well.

```
ng build my-lib --watch
ng s 
npm run storybook
```

In an Angular 9 mono repo with Ivy enabled for the app and all feature libraries this works but if one of the feature itself (lib1 is dependent on another ivy enabled library (lib2) the error below be thrown for each component in the library (lib2)

`zone.js:699 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load comp1.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load comp1.component.html`

I've opened a [Storybook issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9876) for this but I thought I would post an SO question to see if anyone else has found a workaround (other than disabling Ivy for the libraries which is not ideal as then I lose all the new Ivy debugging features).

A sample repo to recreate the issue is available [here](https://github.com/JayChase/storybook-ng-ivy-issue).

Comment: Got the same issue ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working by running [ngcc](https://angular.io/guide/ivy) before running storybook.

```
  "storybook": "ngcc && start-storybook -p 61610",
```